# DateTime on Sticky Notes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetime

Below is the code of `stick Notes` what I am trying to do is wanted current time stamp at sticky notes header in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format

```js
var today = new Date();
var Time = '';
    if (today.getHours() <= 12) {
        Time += ' AM';
    } //end if
    if (today.getHours() > 12) {
        Time += ' PM';
    } //end if

    alert(today.getDate() + '/' + today.getMonth() + '/' + today.getFullYear() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() +  Time);
```

[Sticky Notes](http://jsfiddle.net/Nutvt/42/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your `(function() {..` function a bit like this,

```
 var today = new Date();
        var Time = '';
        if (today.getHours() <= 12) {
            Time += ' AM';
        } //end if
        if (today.getHours() > 12) {
            Time += ' PM';
        } //end if

 var timeStamp= today.getDate() + '/' + today.getMonth() + '/' + today.getFullYear() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() +  Time;
```

And then, you need to add the below line to your `spawn` function,

```
 $('.box-header').html(dd);
```

Like this,

```
var spawn = function () {
    $("body").append(makeNote($(markup)));
    $('.box-header').html(timeStamp);
};
```

**Here is the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Nutvt/170/**

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want that in Header section not in text area

Answer (score 0):

Add a new element `<span>` for the timestamp in `.box-header`:

```
<span class="date-time"></span>
```

With these style rules

```
.date-time {
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Then edit its text

```
$note.find('.date-time').text(timeStamp);
```

Where timeStamp is and constrcuted from:

```
var today = new Date();
var Time = today.getHours() <= 12 ? ' AM' : ' PM';
var timeStamp = today.getDate() + '/' + (today.getMonth()+1) + '/' + today.getFullYear() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes() +  Time;
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nutvt/172/)

Comment: add  `today.getMonth()+1`as it starts with 0 also hours is in `24-Hr` format